# Gettings total memory on windows XP

Tags: c, windows

Alrighly. So. My goal is to get the total system memory on Windows XP - 10. I can use GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory on windows vista and above. And it works like a charm :) however, on windows XP i have to use GlobalMemoryStatusEx which does not account for the hardware reserved memory. So it will report, for example, 511Mb instead of 512Mb. Any clues on how i can fix this problem?

Here's what i have so far. Again. It only doesn't work on XP

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT  0x501
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef (CALLBACK *GPIM)(PULONGLONG);

int GetTotalRam()
{
    unsigned long long total;
    FARPROC FuncAddr = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory");
    if (FuncAddr)
    {
        ((GPIM)FuncAddr)(&total);
    }
    else
    {
        MEMORYSTATUSEX ms;
        memset(&ms, 0, sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX));
        ms.dwLength = sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX);
        GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&ms);
        total = ms.ullTotalPhys / 1024;
    }
    total /= 1024;
    return (int)total;
}
```

Comment: Please explain why 511Mb is not good enough.

Comment: your right. 511Mb out of 512Mb is fine. But when you have 16Gb of RAM youll get 15.8 or 15.9 GB and it just looks gross